Symfony upgrade (4.4 -> 5.4) JsonManifestVersionStrategy issue
By upgrading Symfony from 4.4 to 5.4 I've taken an error

Argument 2 passed to Symfony\Component\Asset\VersionStrategy\JsonManifestVersionStrategy::__construct() must be an instance of Symfony\Contracts\HttpClient\HttpClientInterface or null, instance of GuzzleHttp\Client given, called in /var/www/var/cache/dev/ContainerHhXYcwE/App_KernelDevDebugContainer.php


JsonManifestVersionStrategy is not used in the project directly. Would appreciate any help where to start from?

The answer was found in Why doesn't the asset function work in Symfony 5? posted by Anderson:
framework:
assets:
    json_manifest_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/build/manifest.json'

replace it by
framework:
assets:
    version: 'v2'


You need to upgrade your Guzzle to a version that implements PSR-18.

Update guzzlehttp/guzzle to 7.8.1 (latest) hasn't changed the error.
